# Refresh token and retry the request using RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift, moya

I receive from my backend a accessToken and a refreshToken. When I receive a respons with statusCode 401 I need to replace the accessToken with the refreshToken (accessToken = refreshToken) and try the request again. If the request fail for the third time I need to request the user to log in again. I'm trying to apply this logic using the code described bellow, but it isn't working. The request is not being called again. How can I do this?

```
// example of usage:
public func login(with parameters: LoginParameters) -> Single<User> {
        return provider.rx.request(MultiTarget(UserTarget.login(parameters))).handleResponse(User.self, using: jsonDecoder)
    }

func handleResponse<D: Decodable>(_ type: D.Type, atKeyPath keyPath: String? = nil, using decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(), failsOnEmptyData: Bool = true) -> Single<D> {
        return self.flatMap({ (response) -> Single<D> in

            switch response.statusCode {
            case 200...299:
                RequestsFailedCount.count = 0
                return Single.just(try response.map(type, atKeyPath: keyPath, using: decoder, failsOnEmptyData: failsOnEmptyData))
            case 500:
                return Single.error(try response.map(ResponseError.self))
            default:
                if response.statusCode == 401, let urlResponse = response.response {

                    guard RequestsFailedCount.count <= 3 else {
                        RequestsFailedCount.count = 0
                        return Single.error(InvalidChallengeError())
                    }

                    RequestsFailedCount.count += 1
                    if let challenge = urlResponse.allHeaderFields[HeaderType.authenticate.rawValue] as? String, challenge.contains(self.challenge) {
                        var keychain = KeychainManager()
                        keychain.accessToken = keychain.refreshToken

                        return self.retry(1).map(type, atKeyPath: keyPath, using: decoder, failsOnEmptyData: failsOnEmptyData)
                    } else {
                        return Single.error(try response.map(ResponseError.self))
                    }

                } else {
                    return Single.error(try response.map(ResponseError.self))
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article with a link to code that should help you out: https://medium.com/@danielt1263/retrying-a-network-request-despite-having-an-invalid-token-b8b89340d29

The upshot is that you need to create a token acquisition service that holds onto the current token and is interposed into the network call chain to update the token when necessary...

It would be used like this:

```
func getData<T>(response: @escaping Response, tokenAcquisitionService: TokenAcquisitionService<T>, request: @escaping (T) throws -> URLRequest) -> Observable<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)> {
    return Observable
        .deferred { tokenAcquisitionService.token.take(1) } // gets the current token
        .map { try request($0) } // creates the request using the current token
        .flatMap { response($0) } // gets response from server
        .map { response in
            guard response.response.statusCode != 401 else { throw TokenAcquisitionError.unauthorized }
            return response
        }
        .retryWhen { $0.renewToken(with: tokenAcquisitionService) }
}
```

The tokenAcquisitionService picks up .unauthorized errors and attempts to get a new token from the server. If it's successful, it will retry the chain.

Note that this service is designed to work properly even if you have multiple requests in flight at the same time, and it includes a test harness proving that it works.